# Python 2.7 word counter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a program in python that counts the number of words of a sentence inputted by a user by adding the number of spaces and full stops. The code I have written is:

```
sentence = raw_input('Enter your sentence')
word = 0

for i in sentence:
    if i == ' ' or '.':
        word += 1

print word
```

When I run the code it outputs the total number of characters. Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: `'w' == ' ' or '.'`. Try it in a command prompt.

Comment: `word = len(sentence.split())`. No need for iteration.

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks! :)

Comment: incidentially, you could've also done: `if i == ' ' or i ==  '.'` with your loop, but the loop really isn't necessary here :)

Comment: @DavidZemens That only counts the whitespace runs, not the amount of `' '` and `'.'`

Comment: @PeterWood That's true, but also probably about 99% irrelevant for common usage. OP is attempting to count *words*, and was using spaces and periods as a proxy for word-boundaries, so, the `.` was essentially a false "requirement" for the problem.